# Complex model submission to end point asp.net core 6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swashbuckle

I have the following Model:

```
public class DataForm 
{
    public List<Guid> SelectedTopics { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public AttachmentContent Avatar { get; set; }
    public List<AttachmentContent> Attachments { get; set; }
    public List<ExtraModel> ExtraInformation { get; set; }
}
```

AttachmentContent class is :

```
public class AttachmentContent
{
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

ExtraModel Class is :

```
public class ExtraModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to send the following code to view via Swashbuckle's swagger UI, however, I am not able to parse `Attachments` and `ExtraInformation` in my endpoint which is `[FromForm]`, So I've tried the following mechanism which I have to make a `ModelBinder` for those subclasses and add an `IOperationFilter` to swagger via `swagger.gen()`. however, it does not make the best case possible since I have to filter endpoints within IOperationFilter otherwise it throws an exception when I try to add within the OpenApi's Property Schema because other endpoints don't use the same input model.

my second try was making two separate models and parsing one via `[FromForm]` and the other one with `[FromBody]` however swagger doesn't show the model which is decorated with `[FromForm]` within its UI.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] BodyData body, [FromForm] FormData, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)


public class BodyData 
{
    public List<Guid> SelectedTopics { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<ExtraModel> ExtraInformation { get; set; }
}

    public class FormData
{
    public AttachmentContent Avatar { get; set; }
    public List<AttachmentContent> Attachments { get; set; }
}
```

I was wondering if there is a better way (or best practise) to parse the above model in asp.net core?

Comment: Why not just send the entire model you're sending to the server as FormData? Seems unnecessary to split it up.